# Long Calc Sheet - subtotal at bottom of page, transfer to next page?

Tags: printing, libreoffice-calc, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

Assume i have a LibreOffice Calc sheet spanning multiple pages in printout. Is there a way to calculate a subtotal for each page and print it at the bottom of the respective page as well as at the top of the following page?

I know that one can use subtotals to calculate subtotals automatically, but "only" depending on the data (e.g. dates, names, part numbers) but not simply for each page. Additionally, the calculated subtotal won't appear on the next page.

Answer (score 1):

[Cell values such as totals can be put in a header and/or footer](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=33604) through use of a macro. The macro below was created by Zizi64, Tibor Kovacs, for *Open Office* and is copied from his spreadsheet *Prestige2.ods* from the link above. Modify it for your needs.

This has been tested in *LibreOffice* and it works. Of course, you'll need to enable macros in Options | Security. In the example below, calling macro EditFooterHeader() inserts the value of cell L1 into the footer.

[image: Calling macro EditFooterHeader]

> REM  *****  BASIC  *****
>
> OPTION EXPLICIT
>
> Function EditFooterText(WS_Index as integer, MyFooterLeftText,
>   MyFooterCenterText, MyFooterRightText  as string) as string
>
> Dim oDocument as Object     Dim oSheet as object
>       Dim oPStyle as Object
>       Dim oThisStyle as Object
>       Dim oFContent as Object
>       Dim oText as Object
>       Dim oCursor as Object
>       Dim oField as Object  Dim i as integer    Dim StyleName as string     Dim sAns as String
>
> ```
>   rem Adjusting the actual pagestyle (Pagestyle of actual WorkSheet
> ```
>
> in this document)
>           oDocument = ThisComponent
>           oSheet = oDocument.Sheets.getByIndex( WS_Index-1  )       oPStyle = oDocument.StyleFamilies.getByName("PageStyles")
>           oThisStyle = oPStyle.getByName(oSheet.PageStyle)
>         StyleName = oThisStyle.Name
>
> ```
>     oThisStyle.FooterOn = True
>     'Zizi64: False/True turns on/off the running foot
>
>     oFContent = oThisStyle.RightPageFooterContent
>     'Zizi64: Get the all text from running foot
> ```
>
> '******************************************************** '       oText =
>   oFContent.LeftText
>          '        oCursor = oText.createTextCursor()
>            '        oText.insertString(oCursor, "", True)
>
> '        oCursor.CharHeight = 12 '        oCursor.CharFontName =
>   "Arial" '        oCursor.CharWeight =
>   com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.NORMAL '        oCursor.CharPosture =
>   com.sun.star.awt.FontSlant.NONE '        oCursor.CharUnderline =
>   com.sun.star.awt.FontUnderline.NONE
>            '        ' insert text ... '        oText.insertString(oCursor, MyFooterLeftText, False) 
>   '********************************************************
>
> '        oText = oFContent.CenterText
>            '        oCursor = oText.createTextCursor()
>            '        oText.insertString(oCursor, "", True)
>
> '        oCursor.CharHeight = 12 '        oCursor.CharFontName =
>   "Courir New" '        oCursor.CharWeight =
>   com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.NORMAL '        oCursor.CharPosture =
>   com.sun.star.awt.FontSlant.NONE '        oCursor.CharUnderline =
>   com.sun.star.awt.FontUnderline.NONE
>
> '        oText.insertString(oCursor, MyFooterCenterText, False) 
>   '********************************************************
>
> ```
>     oText = oFContent.RightText
>
>     oCursor = oText.createTextCursor()
>
>     oText.insertString(oCursor, "", True)
>
>     oCursor.CharHeight = 12
>     oCursor.CharFontName = "Times New Roman"
>     oCursor.CharWeight = com.sun.star.awt.FontWeight.NORMAL
>     oCursor.CharPosture = com.sun.star.awt.FontSlant.NONE
>     oCursor.CharUnderline = com.sun.star.awt.FontUnderline.NONE
>
>     oText.insertString(oCursor, MyFooterRightText, False) '********************************************************  
>
>
>
>     oThisStyle.RightPageFooterContent = oFContent      'write content back into running foot
>
>           EditFooterText = StyleName & ": Style modified!:" End function
> ```